# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module while using Firebase Auth, Database and initializeApp

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-authentication

## I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code

```
`const { firebaseApp } = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      const { auth } = firebase.auth(firebaseApp)
      //const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      const { database } = firebase.database(firebaseApp)

      //functions
      function register(){
        email = document.getElementById('email').value 
        your_name = document.getElementById('name').value
        password = document.getElementById('password').value

        if (validate_email(email) == false || validate_password(password) == false){
            alert("Please fill all the fields correctly!")
            return
        } 

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(funtion() ,{
                var: user = auth.currentUser,
                var: database_ref = database.ref(),
                var: user_data = {
                    email : email,
                    your_name : your_name,
                    last_login : Date.now(),
                
                database_ref: child('users/' + user.uid).set(user_data),
                alert: ('User created!')
            },
                
        }
        .catch(funtion(error),{
            var: error_code = error.code,
            var: error_message = error.message, 
            alert(error_message)
        {}})

        )
    }

    function validate_email() {
        expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/
        if (expression.test(email) = true){
            return true
        } else{
            return false
        }
    }

    function validate_password(){
        if (password < 6){
            return false
        } else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

`

I watched a youtube tutorial for firebase authentication, and followed along. I did not install firebase, instead I used firebase CDN and installed firebase tools.
I expected it to work smoothly as shown in the video but it did not.

[The video tutorial I watched](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1ULt_No3IY)

Please do tell me what went wrong/what did I miss out on

Thank you